# Erro acessando vetor de strings

Tags: c, string, array

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char v[]= {'Brasil', 'Alemanha', Japão'};

    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
    printf("%s", v[i]);
    }
}
```

Porém, quando vou compilar abre o terminal e aparece a mensagem:

> paises.exe parou de funcionar

[image: Erro]

O que está errado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O código tem vários erros.

*Strings* devem ser delimitadas por aspas duplas e e não simples que são reservadas apenas para delimitar um caractere.

Está criando um *array* de *strings*, mas está declarando um *array* de caracteres. Com a modificação que eu fiz está criando um *array* de ponteiros para `char` que é exatamente o que produz uma *string*. No caso o compilador vai alocar as três sequências de caracteres em uma área estática e vai colocar um ponteiro para esses textos no *array*.

O laço está lendo um item a mais do que existe, se existem 3, tem que ir até o 2, já que o primeiro começa em 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *v[] = { "Brasil", "Alemanha", "Japão" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) printf("%s\n", v[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Z8jgfZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jnowuhaf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Iterate.c).

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Deu certo :) Guardei sua resposta. Bem completa

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte Olá Guilherme! Marque a resposta como aceita, clicando na marca de verificação do lado esquerdo do texto, please! :)